# Survival analysis cycle time dependent variable

Tags: r, survival, time-varying-covariate

I've a survival analysis study going on and I'm having trouble with dealing with time-dependent variables.  To deal with time-dependent variables I have to create intervals when the variable changes.

One of the variables is "season" wich has values of breeding, post-breeding or winter. Since all the observations start at a different time (different days and different years) it's not easy to o the math for the intervals because there are three changes per year. The final table would be huge, since I have 154 observations and some of them have 5 years of following...
I'm using the R survival package.

Can anyone help me to figure an easy way to deal with this?

Comment: Will this be a Cox proportional hazards model? A parametric model? For Cox PH see [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it's a Cox PH. In fact I'm folowing that vignette, but it doesn't solve my problem for this variable.